# Adding dynamic condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I want to add condition in 'where' clause depends upon 'if' condition like below

```
  Declare @strSQLClause varchar(50)
  If (@QMasterCompanyId='09' and @State='FL' and (@LOB='HO' or @LOB='HP'))
    Begin
        Declare @strMonthsOccupied char(1)
        select Distinct @strMonthsOccupied=sm.MonthsOccupiedDesc from HOStructureRating sr 
            join HOSeleMonthsOccupied sm on sr.MonthsOccupied=sm.MonthsOccupiedCd
            where AppId=@AppId
        If(CONVERT(int,LTRIM(RTrim(@strMonthsOccupied))) > 9)
        Begin
         set @strSQLClause ='AND QuestionCd!=Q8'
        End 
  Else 
    set @strSQLClause =''
  End
```

so that in my Query will work as

```
 select * from SHSeleQuestions where  MasterCompanyId='09'  + @strSQLClause
```

But this approach is not working fine, can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this one is use dynamic sql or other one is below mention :

```
select * 
from SHSeleQuestions 
where  MasterCompanyId='09'  AND
       1 = CASE WHEN LEN(@strSQLClause) > 0 AND QuestionCd != 'Q8' THEN 1 
                WHEN LEN(@strSQLClause) = 0 THEN 1 END
```

Using Dynamic SQL

```
EXEC('select * from SHSeleQuestions where  MasterCompanyId=''09'''  + @strSQLClause ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic SQL, but why not just have two statements that execute SQL, so rather than `set @strSQLClause = 'AND ...'`, simply have a select statement here with the condition(s) you need

```
IF (@QMasterCompanyId='09' AND @State='FL' AND (@LOB='HO' OR @LOB='HP'))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strMonthsOccupied CHAR(1)
    SELECT  DISTINCT @strMonthsOccupied = sm.MonthsOccupiedDesc 
    FROM    HOStructureRating sr 
            INNER JOIN HOSeleMonthsOccupied sm 
                ON sr.MonthsOccupied=sm.MonthsOccupiedCd
    WHERE   AppId=@AppId;

    IF(CONVERT(INT,LTRIM(RTRIM(@strMonthsOccupied))) > 9)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    SHSeleQuestions 
        WHERE   MasterCompanyId='09' 
        AND     QuestionCd!='Q8';
        RETURN;
    END
END

SELECT  * 
FROM    SHSeleQuestions 
WHERE   MasterCompanyId='09';
```

That being said, there are so many issues with the above I don't really know where to begin. You declare your variable then assign it an indeterminate value:

```
DECLARE @strMonthsOccupied CHAR(1)

SELECT  DISTINCT @strMonthsOccupied = sm.MonthsOccupiedDesc 
FROM    HOStructureRating sr 
        INNER JOIN HOSeleMonthsOccupied sm 
            ON sr.MonthsOccupied=sm.MonthsOccupiedCd
WHERE   AppId=@AppId;
```

If the query returns multiple rows then there is no clear logic for which value the variable should be assigned. The nex issue is that this `CHAR(1)` variable is clearly a number based on your attempted conversion:

```
IF(CONVERT(INT,LTRIM(RTRIM(@strMonthsOccupied))) > 9)
```

Why not just cut out the middle man and declare an INT to begin with. The next point is that it is a `CHAR(1)` so isn't actually big enough to store anything greater than 9, so your above condition will **never** be true.

Even if `sm.MonthsOccupiedDesc`, was `10`, the variable would simply be truncated to 1, which is smaller than 9, so fails the condition, e.g.

```
DECLARE @strMonthsOccupied CHAR(1) = '10';
IF(CONVERT(INT,LTRIM(RTRIM(@strMonthsOccupied))) > 9)
    PRINT 'TRUE';
ELSE
    PRINT 'FALSE';
```